# Get-ADGroupMember with groups with members on external domains

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to build a script identifying all members and nested members of the Administrators group. My company currently has 20+ domains, majority of which are not integrated.  Instead, we simply build a trust between domains following acquisition.  The problem is the Administrators group for these domains often has members from one of the external but trusted domains. If i run Get-ADGroupMember I have no problem, but if I run Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive it errors our.  I'm assuming the issue is PS trying looking for the nested membeship of a group located on one of our trusted domains but looking only on the current domain of the Administrators group.

PowerShell Script (replaced server with example domain):

```
$ADGroup = Get-ADGroup -identity "administrators" -Server example.domain.com
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Server example.domain.com -Recursive | Out-GridView
```

Resulting Error Message (replaced server with example domain):

```
PS H:\> $ADGroup = Get-ADGroup -identity "administrators" -Server example.domain.com
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Server example.domain.com -Recursive | Out-GridView
Get-ADGroupMember : There is no such object on the server
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Server example.domain.com -Recursive | Out- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=Administrato...e,DC=domain,DC=com:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : There is no such object on the server,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Comment: Go ahead and add your script to your post, and include the error you receive. That'll help you get started.

Comment: I've added them.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps#notes):

> Notes
>
> This cmdlet does not work when a group has members located in a
>   different forest, and the forest does not have Active Directory Web
>   Service running.

Yes your assumption is correct. (Without an exact error message) You can only enumerate membership from one domain at a time. i.e.

```
Get-ADGroup MyGroup -Server ContosoDC01 | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive -Server ContosoDC01
```

Adding `-Server` highlights that you can only specify one domain that you can enumerate from at a time. Indeed, a straight up `Get-ADGroupMember` will list the distinguished names and SID's for the users/groups, including the SID's for the users/groups from the other domains. But that is all that AD stores, the SID of the user/group. It does not store the membership.

To get the membership requires another, *separate*, call to the other domain to enumerate; and most of the time, cross domain permissions are not set up to allow your current account access to the other domain, and you get:

> Get-ADGroupMember : The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated

Comment: Makes sense. Any cmdlet or comdination thereof that can get around this?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no out of the box cmdlet or function that will get around this. To do this will require a function that will manually enumerate each group individually, and based on the domain, will have to connect (likely with other credentials) to the other domains and enumerate those groups as well. It can be done, but in this case, it may be easier to manually enumerate the groups one domain at a time and group it all together afterwards.